# Ansible regular expression to match a string and extract the line

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to find a string after 1 white space in a line, if it exists then extract the complete line and store in a different variable. I'm using ansible and regular expression. If the string exists in any other place then it should not be matched.

I tried to use regex_match and select but got error.

```
  vars:
    input : "{{ lookup('template', '{{ file }}') }}"
    target: "{{ input | regex_search('^(?=.*\b INPUT\b)(?:\S+){1}(\S*.*)')}}"
```

Error always appear at same place "(?:\S+)".

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character 'S'

The offending line appears to be:

    input : "{{ lookup('template', '{{ file }}') }}"
    target: "{{ input | regex_search('^(?=.*\b INPUT\b)(?:\S+){1}(\S*.*)')}}"

^ here
```

```
    input : "{{ lookup('template', '{{ file }}') }}"
    target: "{{ input | select('match', '^(?=.*\b INPUT\b)(?:\S+){1}(\S*.*)' | list | first}}"

^ here
```

I also tried to include escape character for / but got error as well.

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character 'S'

The offending line appears to be:

   input : "{{ lookup('template', '{{ file }}') }}"
    target: "{{ input | regex_search('^(?=.*/\b INPUT/\b)(?:/\S){1}(/\S*.*)')}}"
                                                                                ^ here
```

My variable file

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 3.3.3.3/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall
-N RH-Firewall
-A RH-Firewall -j INPUT
-A RH-Firewall -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
```

target_rule_set should contains first 5 lines only. Same way if I match for RH-Firewall then it should contain lines 6-11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `regex_findall` with `multiline=True`:

```
(?m)^\S+\s+INPUT\b.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jUKeUM/1). Details:

- `^` - start a line since `(?m)` is used
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `INPUT\b` - `INPUT` as a whole word
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

In the code:

```
target: "{{ input | regex_findall('^\\S+\\s+INPUT\\b.*', multiline=True)}}"
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Regex works but (?m) is not iterating over the variable. It stops after the first occurrence of the search string.

Comment: @Knightfox It is not `(?m)` here to blame. Replace `re.search` with `re.findall`.

Comment: regex_findall still not searching multiline. From ansible docs found that we need to add multiline=True.  ```target: "{{ input | regex_findall('^\\S+\\s+INPUT\\b.*', multiline=True) }}"```

Comment: @Knightfox Great, adjusted the answer.