# Ansible: filter 'stdout' from F5 'bigip_command' module

Tags: ansible, f5

I'm trying to figure out how to filter out just the pool names from the stdout results of the F5 [`bigip_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/f5networks/f5_modules/bigip_command_module.html)_module

```yaml
bigip_command:
  commands:
    - "tmsh list ltm policy {{ item }}"
```

This is the output I get:

```json
TASK [f5_maintenance : tmsh list policies] *************************************
task path: /tmp/bwrap_107256_wsbqhduw/awx_107256_ltm6_eq5/requirements_roles/f5_maintenance/tasks/f5_gather_facts.yml:125
<localhost> Using network group action bigip for bigip_command
<localhost> connection transport is rest
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/network/f5/bigip_command.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: awx
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 && sleep 0'
ok: [LSEL2401.site -> localhost] => (item=policy_test.net_policy) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "executed_commands": [
        "tmsh -c \\\\\\"list ltm policy policy_test.net_policy\\\\\\""
    ], 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null, 
            "commands": [
                "tmsh list ltm policy policy_test.net_policy"
            ], 
            "interval": 1, 
            "match": "all", 
            "provider": {
                "auth_provider": null, 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "server": "LSEL2401.site", 
                "server_port": 443, 
                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                "timeout": null, 
                "transport": "rest", 
                "user": "TOWER", 
                "validate_certs": false
            }, 
            "retries": 10, 
            "transport": "rest", 
            "wait_for": null, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "item": "policy_test.net_policy", 
    "stdout": [
        "ltm policy policy_test.net_policy {\\n    controls { forwarding persistence }\\n    last-modified 2021-09-24:21:53:22\\n    requires { http }\\n    rules {\\n        policy_test.net_rule1 {\\n            actions {\\n                0 {\\n                    forward\\n                    select\\n                    pool policy_test.net_pool1\\n                }\\n                1 {\\n                    persist\\n                    cookie-insert\\n                    name FSdefault\\n                }\\n            }\\n            conditions {\\n                0 {\\n                    http-uri\\n                    path\\n                    starts-with\\n                    values { / }\\n                }\\n            }\\n            ordinal 1\\n        }\\n        policy_test.net_rule2 {\\n            actions {\\n                0 {\\n                    forward\\n                    select\\n                    pool policy_test.net_pool2\\n                }\\n                1 {\\n                    persist\\n                    cookie-insert\\n                    name KSexpress\\n                }\\n            }\\n            conditions {\\n                0 {\\n                    http-uri\\n                    path\\n                    starts-with\\n                    values { /test }\\n                }\\n            }\\n        }\\n    }\\n    status published\\n    strategy first-match\\n}"
    ], 
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "ltm policy policy_test.net_policy {", 
            "    controls { forwarding persistence }", 
            "    last-modified 2021-09-24:21:53:22", 
            "    requires { http }", 
            "    rules {", 
            "        policy_test.net_rule1 {", 
            "            actions {", 
            "                0 {", 
            "                    forward", 
            "                    select", 
            "                    pool policy_test.net_pool1", 
            "                }", 
            "                1 {", 
            "                    persist", 
            "                    cookie-insert", 
            "                    name FSdefault", 
            "                }", 
            "            }", 
            "            conditions {", 
            "                0 {", 
            "                    http-uri", 
            "                    path", 
            "                    starts-with", 
            "                    values { / }", 
            "                }", 
            "            }", 
            "            ordinal 1", 
            "        }", 
            "        policy_test.net_rule2 {", 
            "            actions {", 
            "                0 {", 
            "                    forward", 
            "                    select", 
            "                    pool policy_test.net_pool2", 
            "                }", 
            "                1 {", 
            "                    persist", 
            "                    cookie-insert", 
            "                    name KSexpress", 
            "                }", 
            "            }", 
            "            conditions {", 
            "                0 {", 
            "                    http-uri", 
            "                    path", 
            "                    starts-with", 
            "                    values { /test }", 
            "                }", 
            "            }", 
            "        }", 
            "    }", 
            "    status published", 
            "    strategy first-match", 
            "}"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here's my task.

```yaml
- name: Collect bigip facts
  bigip_device_info:
    gather_subset: 
      - ltm-policies
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
  register: policy_facts

- name: Policies
  set_fact:
    policy: "{{ policy_facts.ltm_policies|default({}) | to_json | from_json | json_query(query_string) }}"
  vars:
   query_string: "[?contains(name, '{{ app_fqdn }}')].name"

- name: policy name 
  debug:
    msg: "{{ policy }}"

- name: tmsh list policies
  bigip_command:
    commands:
     - "tmsh list ltm policy {{ item }} "
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{ policy }}"
  register: layer7_pools

- name: VIP Results stdout_lines
  debug: msg="{{ layer7_pools.results }}"
```

Comment: Can you also provide a full description of your task? Especially how did you registered the results, how did you got `layer7_pools`? Since the content of `stdout_lines` looks like JSON, if you `register: result` and print out `"{{ result.json }}"`, would that work?

Comment: Or are you just using the [f5networks.f5_modules.bigip_command - Return Vaules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/f5networks/f5_modules/bigip_command_module.html#return-values)?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to filter the return values to only get the pools.  I need the pool information to further lookup the members of the pool and their status.

Comment: After some research it seems that you like to do [JSON parsing in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844720/) and [to get the values from Ansible JSON stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640231/). According this can you check the output from `{{ layer7_pools.stdout | from_json}}` first and see if it gives you a better access to the data?

Comment: This is the message I get when using {{ layer7_pools.stdout | from_json}}.

"Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ layer7_pools.stdout | from_json}}): expected string or buffer",
    "_ansible_no_log": false

Answer (score 0):

After research I've learned from F5 documentation that the output of `tmsh list` is declarative but not JSON. For JSON output they referenced the REST API.

Since the value of `stdout_lines` is a list of list(s) with one element only, and `stdout` just a list with one string element only including the line breaks (`\n`), I've focused to get the necessary result by searching within the string.

To do so I've setup a test based on your provided out results

```yaml
- name: Set result value for bigip_command tmsh list
  set_fact:
    layer7_pools:
      stdout: [
        "ltm policy policy_test.net {\n ... controls  strategy first-match\n}"
      ]
      stdout_lines: [
        [
          "ltm policy policy_test.net {",
          "    controls { forwarding }",
          ...
          "    strategy first-match",
          "}"
        ]
      ]
```

and setup the following filter.

```yaml
- name: Show result, filter for pool names
  debug:
    msg: "{{ layer7_pools.stdout[0] | regex_findall('pool .*', multiline=True) }}"
```

Resulting in a output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result, filter for pool names] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - pool policy_test_rule1.net_pool
  - pool policy_test_rule2_pool
```

**Thanks to**

- [Ansible: Regular expression to match a string and extract the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869119/)
- [Ansible: Extracting part of the string `regex_search` and save the output as a variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033936/)

Comment: I'm now getting the following error.

     {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ layer7_pools.stdout[0] | regex_findall('pool .*', multiline=True) }}): expected string or buffer",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}

@U880D

Comment: @SDay, what is the content now of the variable `layer7_pools` now?

Comment: I update my original question with the entire output from the var layer7_pools and it includes the stdout and stdout_lines

Comment: Ah, I see. You are [registering variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop). My examples works because it doesn't has a loop implement (yet). I think you need to `loop: "{{ layer7_pools }}"` and to `debug: msg: "{{ item[0] ...`. Maybe I can setup for such too.